# Setting environment variables for an IOS application running outside of debugger

Tags: ios, xcode, variables, environment

I have an IOS application which uses environment variables and am able to set those without any issue using XCode during development. However I would like to figure out how to set these same environment variables when not running via XCode, i.e. when starting the app normally from springboard.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not possible on a normal device. Maybe under jailbreak.